# Prometheus /etc/config/prometheus.yml: no such file or directory with Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, dockerfile, prometheus, kubernetes-helm

I tried to deploy prometheus with using `https://prometheus-community.github.io/helm-charts`
But I wanted to have a custom `prometheus.yml` Therefore the approach I used is the build the prometheus docker image by copying the customised prometheus.yml file. (via a simple pipeline)

Dockerfile I use

```
FROM quay.io/prometheus/prometheus:v2.26.0
ADD config /etc/config/
```

It builds the image successfully and when I try to deploy this image via the helm,
container fails with the following error.

```
level=error ts=2021-10-14T15:26:02.525Z caller=main.go:347 msg="Error loading config (--config.file=/etc/config/prometheus.yml)" err="open /etc/config/prometheus.yml: no such file or directory"
```

I am not sure if this is the ideal approach.
What can I do to have a customised `prometheus.yml` inside the prometheus pod.
(I can have the config within the values.yaml in helm but I prefer to have a separate file. So I can manage it easily)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The challenege was to manage the prometheus.yml as a seperate file. I have found `extraConfigmapMounts` option in the community Prometheus stack.

Therefore creating a configMap using the `prometheus.yml` and mount it to the application seems like a good way of achieving it.
Simply use of the value `server.extraConfigmapMounts` to add the configuration.

```
extraConfigmapMounts:
    - name: prometheus-configmap
      mountPath: /prometheus/config/
      subPath: ""
      configMap: <configMap name>
      readOnly: true
```

Answer (score 0):

Building an image just to change configuration isn't a convenient way to configure an application. Consider, you will have to update the image (build, push, pull) each time you need to change configuration. Besides, this community Prometheus stack has an easy way to customize `prometheus.yml` via the [values.yml](https://github.com/prometheus-community/helm-charts/blob/main/charts/prometheus/values.yaml#L1356):

```yaml
serverFiles:
  prometheus.yml:
    rule_files:
      - /etc/config/recording_rules.yml
      - /etc/config/alerting_rules.yml
      - /etc/config/rules
      - /etc/config/alerts
    scrape_configs:
      - job_name: prometheus
        static_configs:
          - targets:
            - localhost:9090
```

You can add the desired changes under `serverFiles."prometheus.yml"` key and then simply redeploy the stack.

Comment: Hey, Thank you for the reply. 
Yes I know that I can simply update the values.yml. 
But the requirement was to manage the prometheus.yml as a separate file. I found out another way of achieving it. 
I have created a configMap with the prometheus.yml and mounted it using the  extraConfigmapMounts.